# Ajax Form Success Submit But Not Response Message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I can send data with this form but I can not get any response I tried many different methods but I did not see the mistake.

Where exactly am I making mistakes?

**Javascript**

```
$("partUnitIDForm").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: rootSite + '/includes/ajaxs/partUnitID.php',
        data: $('partUnitIDForm').serialize(),
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#partUnitIDResult').html('processing');
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#partUnitIDResult').html('failure');
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#partUnitIDResult').html(response);
            // Remove the option
            opt.remove()
        },
        timeout: 3000,
```

**Form:**

```
<form action="https://www.example.com/includes/ajaxs/partUnitID.php" id="partUnitIDForm" name="partUnitIDForm" method="post">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="partUnitID" name="partUnitID" type="text">
  </div>  
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<div id="partUnitIDResult"></div>
```

Comment: if the success callback executes then probably the issue is with the php code

Comment: Try putting a console.log in the response to see if the php page is even sending a response or not

Comment: We don't have all you javascript, but you don't use # in your jquery selector id. And do you see you request in the chrome inspector ? (Networks -> XHR)

Comment: There are many things that could've gone wrong: (1) if you're using a recent version of jQuery, note that `jqXHR.success()` has been deprecated. (2) you have not showed what your server-side code is. In what format is it returning the response? JSON? Plain text?

Comment: ``$("partUnitIDForm")`` is wrong and must be ``$("#partUnitIDForm")`` i think

Comment: @ParijatPurohit I triend "console.log" method but I did not get a response again

Comment: @Samy Yes, I checked but everything seems normal. I have multiple form and all form is working but this form ia not working. I will try the XHR method presently

Comment: @Terry I use this version 3.1.1. I tried both ways for server side, `JSON` and `Plain Text`. the result did not change.

Comment: @mtizziani I noticed my mistake and I fixed but still not working.

Comment: Check your browser console and under the network tab, inspect your XHR responses.

Comment: Have you fixed it at both locations?  It must be $('#partUnitIDForm').serialize() and $('#partUnitIDForm').submit()

Comment: Problem solved. Reason: This is because the other person wrote JavaScript for this form. So the codes overlap. Everyone thank you for your help.